# What could be causing the Visual Studio 2010 IDE to freeze?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What does this icon mean?

[image: Document icon with two plus signs in the status bar]

After some coding, this icon appeared in the status bar and the IDE was frozen.itself.

I cannot manage anymore with this icon is appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio might crash with low memory on win7/32bit systems. I donot now if this is the symptom you describe.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407021(VS.100).aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here.

It looks like two yellow pluses. Are you using some kind of plug-in for versioning system? 
I recommend that you download Process Exporer from sysinternals and look at the calling stack and see where it hangs.